# How to have a prefilled forms with data from api and validate the forms with Element UI Vue

Tags: validation, vue.js, element-ui

So i have a data which i got from an api,

```
{
"companyName": "Niche",
}
```

and i want them to fill a form and with validation using element-ui el-form component before submitting the data. And this is the form:

template:

```
<el-form ref="form" :model="form" :rules="formRules">
 <el-form-item :prop="companyName">
    <el-input :value="response.companyName" :placeholder="response.companyName" class="input-company-name"></el-input>
 </el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

script:

```
data() {

 return {
  form: {
   companyName: '',
  },
  formRules: {
    companyName: [{
      required: true,
      message: 'Please input Company Name',
      trigger: 'blur',
    }],
  }
 },
 methods: {
  submitForm(form){
   this.$refs[form].validate((valid)=> {
    // perform http request
  })
 }
```

i've tried

```
<el-form-item :prop="'response.' + index + '.companyName'">
 <el-input :value="response.companyName" :placeholder="response.companyName" class="input-company-name"></el-input>
</el-form-item>
```

but it's either i can't get the data to fill the form, or the validation didn't work. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Validations are only executed when the form field is touched. Unless you execute the validation manually =>

```
this.$refs[form].validate((valid)=>
```

So probably when the form is loaded you should execute the validation

And when executing

```
this.$refs[form].validate((valid)=> {
   if (valid) {
     ... execute http request
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: yep thats exactly what i did. but still cant get the validation going :/

Comment: Did you take a look at the life cycle of vue https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html, mounted function. or place a watch on your form